# Jmter, duplicate list of sample result

Tags: jmeter

I had recorded the script using blaze meter plugin, and using ultimate thread group, I am not able to figure out:

1. Why there is delay in sending first request? I have not set any delayed and start-time is also for 1 second
2. Also in my result tree I am seeing multiple http requests called. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. We are not telepathic enough to guess why do you have the "delay" without seeing your test plan, most probably there is something like "Think-Time" or other [Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) there

   [image]

   having non-zero "Thread Delay" value. This is to simulate real user using the real browser. Real users don't hammer the application under test non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations so most probably this delay is due to the timer action
2. If you look at `Defaults` configuration element at the "Advanced" tab there is a setting instructing JMeter to download so-called ["Embedded Resources"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses). In the main HTML response there are multiple referenced elements like images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. and JMeter parses the main HTML response, extracts these resources from there and downloads them as this is what real browsers do.

   [image]